# Does it matter for DB efficiency what number is SQL Server's index column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql, indexing

I'm creating a new SQL Server 2008 database and I was always wondering, efficiency-wise, does it matter where I place the index column?

For instance, this:

```
--ID is primary key
CREATE TABLE tbl (ID INT, dtIn DATETIME2, dtOut DATETIME2, Type INT)
INSERT tbl VALUES
(1, '01:30', '02:00', 1),
(2, '02:30', '03:00', 1),
(3, '10:30', '11:00', 2)

CREATE INDEX idx_Type ON tbl(Type)
```

versus this:

```
--ID is primary key
CREATE TABLE tbl (ID INT, Type INT, dtIn DATETIME2, dtOut DATETIME2)
INSERT tbl VALUES
(1, 1, '01:30', '02:00'),
(2, 1, '02:30', '03:00'),
(3, 2, '10:30', '11:00')

CREATE INDEX idx_Type ON tbl(Type)
```

Comment: No it doesn't. It does however matter [what place in the index the column has](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/9406/5203).

Comment: Oh I can't post that as an answer. Oh well. Thanks for that. Not sure how to elaborate on that one.

Comment: Thanks. I know it's a newbie question... but I'm trying to learn. Also why can't you post it as an answer?

Comment: Speaking of places in the index, I'm going to be doing selections as such "WHERE Type = N AND " complex condition that involves dtIn and dtOut columns. Shall I change how I structure the index then?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about DBA concerns and should therefore be on dba.SE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well , it sounds interesting, depends on how you implement

```
Single column index -it does not matter 

Multi-column index - order of the column does matter in the index,
                     but not in the table
```

[Ben has a proof](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2718/sql-server-index-column-order--does-it-matter/) here

Comment: What matters to multi-column index, is the order the columns in the index have. Not the order of columns in the actual table.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, column placement in a table has nothing to do with the amount of resources used